# Recommendation for an EC2 Instance Stack

Tags: amazon-ec2, lamp

Our development servers are on Amazons EC2.

We would ideally like the following:

PHP 5.3.x
Oracle Drivers
mHash
mCrypt
Apache

Does anyone have a recommendation on a good place to get a stack that would meet most of those needs with a minimum of additional configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For updated base AMI's you can check Ubuntu canonical AMI's found at Eric's site: www.alestic.com.

The Amazon AMI was also release if you prefer CentOS distro. http://bit.ly/a5fcz3

For security reasons, I suggest you build your own LAMP stack.

Of course there are many existing LAMP AMI's you can find.

Answer (score 0):

We are bootstrapping our instances using [chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef) and a service called [Scalarium](http://github.com/till/easybib-cookbooks/). Depending on what we setup and configure, it takes up to 8 minutes for the instance to become operational.

Feel free to check out my [chef recipes](http://github.com/till/easybib-cookbooks/), specifically the one for php-fpm:
http://github.com/till/easybib-cookbooks/tree/master/php-fpm/

I'm also working on [a custom php5 debian package](http://github.com/till/php5-easybib) to speed up the PHP installation.